FastAPI App using Zoom Webhook runs locally but not in Docker where Zoom Signature Rejected
I built a FastAPI App that receives meeting/recordings events from Zoom API through Zoom Webhook. I use ngrok for the webhook URL. Everything works perfectly when running it locally.
However, I built an image for the app in Docker, and when I try to run it, I get "signature rejected".
I verified that I"m using the same environment variables, the same environment (even libraries version since I"m using poetry so the creation of the environment is specific and identical).
I verified that the container timezone is same as my host system timezone. But I'm still getting the error.
Here is the code of the signature verification function:
def signature_verified(self, headers: dict, body: bytes):

    # Extract the necessary components from headers and body
    timestamp = headers['x-zm-request-timestamp']
    if not timestamp:
        return False  # Timestamp is missing, cannot verify
            # Construct the message string
    decoded_body = body.decode('utf-8')
    message = f"v0:{timestamp}:{decoded_body}"
    
    print("Constructed Message:", message)

    #get zoom webhook secret token
    secret_token = os.getenv('ZOOM_WEBHOOK_SECRET_TOKEN')
    if not secret_token:
        print("Secret token is missing.")
        return False
    # Create the HMAC SHA-256 hash
    hash_for_verify = hmac.new(secret_token.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    # Create the signature
    generated_signature = f"v0={hash_for_verify}"

    print("Computed HMAC:", hash_for_verify)

    human_readable = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))

    print("Timestamp from Zoom:", headers['x-zm-request-timestamp'])
    print("Human-readable timestamp:", human_readable)


    print("Generated Signature:", generated_signature)
    print("Expected Signature:", headers.get('x-zm-signature'))

    return headers.get('x-zm-signature') == generated_signature

Here is where the main.py where it triggers that function:
 @app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request: Request):
    # Get the request body and headers
    client_host = request.client.host
    print(f"Request from IP: {client_host}")
    
    body = await request.body()
    headers = request.headers
    try:
        # Verify the request came from Zoom
        if zoom_client.signature_verified(headers, body):
            # Parse the request body as JSON
            event_data = await request.json()

            # Check if this is a URL validation request
            if event_data["event"] == "endpoint.url_validation":
                logging.info("WEBHOOK: URL validation request received")
                return zoom_client.url_verification(event_data)

            elif event_data["event"] == "session.ended":
                # Handle session.ended event
                topic = event_data["payload"]["object"]["topic"]
                id = event_data["payload"]["object"]["id"]
                logging.info(f"WEBHOOK: Session ended: {topic}({id}))")
                return {"message": "Received session.ended event."}
            else:
                logging.error("WEBHOOK: Unauthorized request to Webhook: Signature verified rejected")
                return {"message": "Unauthorized request to Zoom Webhook"}, 401

     except Exception as e:
         logging.error(f"WEBHOOK: Error processing webhook: {e}")
         return {"message": "Error processing Zoom Webhook"}, 500

pyproject.toml file:
    [tool.poetry]
name = "zoomerizer"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "An app that summarizes the recordings of zoom meetings. It communicates with Zoom API."
authors = ["<email>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
fastapi = "^0.109.2"
redis = "^5.0.1"
types-redis = "^4.6.0.20240218"
uvicorn = "^0.27.1"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.1"
requests = "^2.31.0"
logging = "^0.4.9.6"
coloredlogs = "^15.0.1"
verboselogs = "^1.7"
SQLAlchemy = "^2.0.27"
langchain = "^0.1.8"
openai = "^1.12.0"
langchain-openai = "^0.0.8"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Dockerfile:
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install Poetry
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.2
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

# Copy only requirements to cache them in docker layer
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* ./

# Project initialization:
# This does not actually populate your project with Python packages
# It only copies the project setup files
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Exposing the port that Gunicorn will run on
EXPOSE 8000

# Copying everything from the current directory into the container
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser:appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["uvicorn", "zoomerizer.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

ngrok url (that is put in Zoom API Webhook) is forwarding to http://localhost:8000
And here is the error I get when I run this command:
docker run -e TZ=Europe/Berlin -p 8000:8000 --env-file .env zoomerizer

Error:
INFO:     192.168.65.1:64127 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2024-05-30 14:38:40,320 - ERROR - WEBHOOK: Unauthorized request to Webhook: Signature verified rejected

The signature generated when tested with Zoom signature returns false, while locally without Docker it returns true. Can you please help me identify the reason?

Looks like something with headers.
Do you use ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 0.0.0.0:8000. host-header parameter in cmd? Or could you check it?

@DmitriGalkin Are you doubting the problem relies in the connection between ngrok and Docker? If so I'm getting the "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK in the terminal when the app is running on docker, so I suppose no problem there. I start ngrok locally using "ngrok http 8000"

Have you tried my advice with headers?
